# filter updates based on tag selection AND show all tags that pertain to each update

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

`updates`, `tags`, `updates_tags`

I use the following query to filter out the updates based on selected tags.

```
SELECT 
`updates`.`id` as `update_id`,
`updates`.`body` as `update`,   
group_concat(DISTINCT `tags`.`title` ORDER BY `tags`.`title` ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS tags
FROM `updates`
LEFT JOIN `updates_tags` ON `updates`.`id` = `updates_tags`.`update_id`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `updates_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` 
WHERE `updates_tags`.`tag_id` IN (?) #### <- FILTER ####
GROUP BY `updates`.`id`
```

I would like to keep the filter **BUT** also have a column that has all the tags that relate to the updates. Probably something to do with `GROUP_CONCAT` or maybe I need an extra `JOIN`.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think my question is valid. Yes, I don't have a dataset but my explanation was clear enough for somebody to understand what I'm asking. I got a correct answer.

Comment: In the absence of a data set and desired result l, I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks good. You just need to pass in a comma delimited list of tag ids for your filter.

```
SELECT 
    `u1`.`id` AS `update_id`,
    `u1`.`body` AS `update`,   
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `t1`.`title` ORDER BY `t1`.`title` ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS `tags`
FROM `updates` AS `u1`
INNER JOIN `updates_tags` AS `ut1` ON (`u1`.`id` = `ut1`.`update_id`)
INNER JOIN `tags` AS `t1` ON (`ut1`.`tag_id` = `t1`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `updates_tags` AS `ut2` ON (`u1`.`id` = `ut2`.`update_id`)
INNER JOIN `tags` AS `t2` ON (`ut2`.`tag_id` = `t2`.`id` AND `t2`.`id` IN (3, 4))
GROUP BY `u1`.`id`
```

Comment: I want to show updates that have all of the tag ids, not just one or more, BUT STILL FILTER based on the tag ids. At the moment if i filter based on tag ids (like you did) i don't get all the tags that pertain to the update.

Comment: Thanks @Rob wouldn't of figured this out!